# How do I get wireshark script that starts when network connects and logs to unique timestamp file?

Tags: networking, scripts, wireshark

I'm using ubuntu 16.04
I've installed wireshark on it and I know how to start it manually each time. 
What I would like is to have a script that automatically starts whenever I start my connection to the internet eg lan or wifi
I'd like to timestamp the output and put it in a directory.

I've had a look around and even at wireshark but they seem to have scripts for windows not ubuntu. Would appreciate assistance.

Comment: What sort of traffic do you want to capture ? TCP ?  UDP ?  Any specific protocols ?

Comment: Instead of wireshark you can use `tcpdump`, which is a console program and is able to create text files as well as binary files readable by wireshark.

Comment: In addition to what @ridgy mentioned, you can also run tcpdump in a mode that will automatically name the files including the date and time in the file name and to make a new file every so often. For example, ten minutes per file, `sudo tcpdump -i enp4s0 -w 'ext-%F-%H-%M-%S.bin' -G 600`. Then you can go back and look at any particular file using wireshark, usually based on some log file entry that you want to investigate in more detail.

Comment: Thanks, i appreciate it that, but then why bother with wireshark? Should I ditch it altogether or does it give additional info that tcpdump does not?

Comment: Yes, you can ditch wireshark, however I prefer it for looking into stuff from the logs because it allows filtering and such on the fly and more detailed expansion of some of the packet contents.